# Error comes when running Apache Spark on Yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm a rookie in Big Data.
I just want to run the code `spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client`, and the error comes as this after a very long waiting time:

```
20/09/27 21:14:55 ERROR cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: The YARN application has already ended! It might have been killed or the Application Master may have failed to start. Check the YARN application logs for more details.
20/09/27 21:14:55 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1601211854090_0001 failed 2 times due to Error launching appattempt_1601211854090_0001_000002. Got exception: java.net.ConnectException: Call From localhost/127.0.0.1 to localhost:46345 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor44.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:824)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:754)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1544)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1486)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1385)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:118)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.startContainers(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.startContainers(ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.java:128)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

This just happens when I want to run spark on Yarn. I can use spark-shell in my centos7.
I have added a lot of things to my `yarn-site.sh`:

```
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
        <value>4</value>
    </property>
```

And my `spark-env.sh`:

```
export SCALA_HOME=/home/scala-2.11.12
export JAVA_HOME=/home/java/jdk1.8.0_251
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.10.0
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.10.0/bin/hadoop classpath)
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.10.0/etc/hadoop
export SPARK_MASTER_HOST=192.168.99.104
```

And I really don't know what can I do to save my Spark.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to find your application on YARN History Server and access the logs, they may be more informative with the actual error which indicates the real problem.

In your case, search for `application_1601211854090_0001` .

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't find the log by running `yarn log -applicationId` . So I go to check the log on 192.168.99.104:8088 and find that the error is `Call From localhost/127.0.0.1 to localhost:46345 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused` and I still don't know what it is.